# I don't understand the result of this little program

Tags: pointers, arguments, malloc

i've made this little program to test a little part of a bigger program.

```
    int main()
{
    char c[]="ddddddddddddd";
    char *g= malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    *g=NULL;
    strcpy (g,c);

    printf("Hello world %s!\n",g);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the function would return "Hello World dddd" ,since the length of g is 4*sizeof(char), but it returns  " Hello World ddddddddddddd ".Can you explain me Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, it's undefined behaviour.

The `strcpy` function will happily copy *all* those characters in `c` *regardless* of the size of `g`.

That's because it copies characters up to the first `\0` in `c`. In this particular case it may corrupt your heap, or it may not, depending on the minimum size of  things that get allocated in the heap (many have a "resolution" of sixteen bytes for example).

There are other functions you can use (though they're optional) if you want your code to be more robust, such as `strncpy` (provided you understand the limitations), or `strcpy_s()`, as detailed in Appendix K of the ISO C11 standard (and earlier iterations as well).

Or, if you can't use those for some reason, it's up to the *developer* to ensure they don't break the rules.

Comment: If i use a for loop , willi get the same wrong result ?

Comment: @CorneilleK, it depends on what controls the `for` loop. If it's the `strlen()` of `c`, then you'll have the same problem, yes. There are other ways as per my update.